# Can a woman deny a man information on what stands on a potential child of his birth certificate?

Tags: united-states

If a man request information on whether he has been legally declared the father of a child by a mother, can the woman deny him this information? Talking about US jurisdictions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can go to the court and request the birth certificate. If you are on it as a parent, they will give it to you. No need to involve the mother at all.

Comment: You may even be able to get a copy of the certificate directly from the state or county vital statistics office, without going to court.  For instance, [here's how to do it in Texas](https://www.dshs.texas.gov/vs/reqproc/Ordering-Birth-Certificates-Online.shtm).

Comment: So the answer to his question would be, yes, she can deny his request.

Comment: @user6726 Yes, if you want to take the question literally. I read it as "can a woman block a man from getting information about a birth certificate". Obviously the woman can refuse to answer the man herself, but the man in this situation has options to get the information requested...

Comment: I assume that if you are not on the birth certificate, then you won't get it, but that also answers your question whether you are on the birth certificate.